# Regex replace with capturing groups

Tags: .net, regex, replace

I wish to refactor code using .NET regular expressions. The aim is to split declarations and assignments (for backwards compatibility with SQL 2005).

Sample Input:

```
DECLARE @clientCode char(10), @city nvarchar(100) = '', @country char(2) = 'US',
   @clientId int
```

Desired Output:

```
DECLARE @clientCode char(10), @city nvarchar(100), @country char(2),
   @clientId int
SELECT @city = '', @country = 'us'
```

This is what I have so far to match the input:

```
DECLARE\s+
(
    ,?
    (@\w+\s+)
    (\(.+\))?
    (\=\s+\w+)?
)+
```

What replacement regex could I use to get the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you get this working with a `RegEx`, it will be a maintenance nightmare.

I suggest you write out some well commented string manipulation in code.

Comment: Reluctantly I think you're right. Using regular expressions for this would be maintenance headache.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just for the fun of it, if you happen to have [SQL Server 2012 feature pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065) at hand, you might use [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Parser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee213392.aspx) to parse your existing SQL 20xx code and generate the equivalent 2005 code. [You might even do so with PowerShell](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2012/03/13/parsing-t-sql-the-easy-way.aspx). Nice weekend project, eh? :-)

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for pointing me to the `Transact-SQL Language Service` for parsing TSQL.